# ios obtain same size image for server upload (for all 2x, 3x devices)

Tags: ios, xcode, image, autoscaling

My app provides several avatar images for users to select, the selected avatar image will be uploaded to server.

I would like to upload the biggest size (3x size) of avatar image to server for all kinds of devices (even for 2x devices), so that all users will have the same size of avatar image no matter what devices they are using.

It seems not possible for 2x devices to load 3x images due to app thinning.
What is the best way to achieve this while prevent as most duplicated images as it could?

Thanks

Comment: What about having the avatar images on the server side and only sending the identifier of the avatar?

Comment: Are you having the avatar already in the app bundle? If yes then why you need to upload since you already have the avatar in your machine? If the image comes from photos or camera then it wont have 2x or 3x, just matter how you resize it

Comment: @the4kman Storing the images identifier on the server should be one of the several best ways to handle this situation normally. However, I cannot change server side code for some reasons, that's why I need to think a way to add new features on the server with the old architecture.